# Не удалось загрузить элемент панели элементов. Он будет удален из панели элементов

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при добавлении своего пользовательского элемента: "Не удалось загрузить элемент "Название" панели элементов. Он будет удален из панели элементов"

Хоть целевая платформа указана как Any CPU, но всёравно элемент не добавляется.

Пытался добавлять сторонние элементы ( т.е от других разработчиков, с другим кодом ), создавать новый проект - не помогло.

VS 2019

Проект Windows Forms.
Вот код элемента:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pleer
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Код UserControl1.Designer.cs :

```
namespace Pleer
{
    partial class UserControl1
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором компонентов

        /// <summary> 
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // UserControl1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Name = "UserControl1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Что в UserControl1.Desogner.cs файле?

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, что откликнулись. Сейчас добавлю код в тело вопроса.

Comment: @aepot Добавил код.

Comment: Так он пустой. Быть может визуал не может его подхватить, потому что нечего рендерить? Быть может надо обработчики какие добавить. Но это догадки.

Comment: @aepot А чего тогда пользовательские компоненты не подходят? https://github.com/ukushu/TextProgressBar Вот этот например... Единственное что.... Я просто закидываю файл компонента в проект, если он пользовательский,  это правильно?

Comment: Наверное нет. Я бы создал библиотеку пользовательских контролов, в студии есть такой шаблон.